# Csv file with entities

Tags: watson-conversation

I need a csv file containing entities, values and synonyms. (For Ibm Watson Conversation). Thanks. I have tried converting txt files to csv files but there are minor errors. Can someone please help?

Edited: I need a csv file WITH entities. The entities should contain values and synonyms such as:

```
'entity','value','synonyms'
example: weekday,Monday,Mon
weekday,Tuesday,Tue,Tues
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on entities?

Answer (score 1):

The following documentation page explains how to create the modified-CSV file for entity importing. As well as sample data.

http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/entities.html#importing-entities

To summarize, the format - currently looks as follows:
On each line in the csv file you specify:

`<entity>,<value>,<synonyms>`

where `<entity>` is the name of an entity, `<value>` is a value for the entity, and `<synonyms>` is a comma-separated list of synonyms for that value.

For example:

`weekday,Tuesday,Tue,Tues`

So you can create a csv file by using a common text editor and put there lines:

`weekday,Monday,Mon
weekday,Tuesday,Tue,Tues
weekday,Wednesday,Wed
weekday,Thursday,Thu,Thurs
weekday,Friday,Fri
weekday,Saturday,Sat
weekday,Sunday,Sun,Sundy`

to define an entity capturing the weekday.

Comment: yes I've gone through this. I wanted to know if we have a readymade entity csv file available? or should I do it manually because there are many synonyms and many words in a dictionary ??

Comment: There are system entities which are prebuilt. But otherwise you make your own entity files, and then only for what you need. If your solution requires a lot of synonyms then you should be using intents, not entities. As intents have the machine learning component.